# Change TextColor while scrolling in PickerView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, datepicker

I want to change the TextColor of picker view. I am able to change textColor after `didSelectRow` method called.

But I want to change TextColor also when the text is coming in the selectedRow area same as like Clock app in iPhone.

**Mycode:**

```
-(NSAttributedString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSAttributedString *str= [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",row] attributes:@{
                                                                                                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]
                                                                                                                             }];
    if([pic selectedRowInComponent:component]==row)
    str= [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",row] attributes:@{
                                                                                                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]
                                                                                                                             }];
    return str;
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    [pic reloadComponent:component];
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

[image]

Comment: Did you manage it ??

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired effect in your example with multiple PickerViews i.e. the main PickerView in the center with the large type and differentiating color.  Then place two smaller picker views above and below, ensure all of these are restricted in size so that only one row height is visible.  Make sure to only set the delegate for the main object and bring it forward in the View hierarchy, when that is scrolled manually offset the the content of the other pickers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am confuse with **"Make sure to only set the delegate for the main object and bring it forward in the View hierarchy, when that is scrolled manually offset the the content of the other pickers."**

I am not getting this,sorry